# How to select the recently added record in the listbox?

Tags: ms-access, vba

First off, my question is **not** in regards to selecting the last added record in a `List Box`. That can be achieved using this:

```
Me.MyList.Selected(Me.MyList.ListCount - 1) = True
```

Basically, I have a `Form` with a `List Box` that is bounded to a table. Let's call this table `tblMyData`. In this table, I have 4 fields, lets call it `ID, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName`.

I have 3 `Text Box` that corresponds to the appropriate `FirstName, MiddleName, and LastName` field values that can be entered.

When the form loads up, the `List Box` queries the table for data and displays it appropriately.

I've implemented the functionality to add the user input data to the `tblMyData` table:

```
Private Sub addRecord_Click()

    CurrentDB.Execute "INSERT INTO tblMyData (FirstName, MiddleName, LastName)" _
        & "VALUES ('" & Me.textBox_FirstName & "', '" & Me.textBox_MiddleName & "', '" & Me.textBox_LastName & "')"

    Me.MyList.Requery

End Sub
```

The problem is that the `tblMyData` is sorted **first** by `FirstName`, **then** by `LastName`. Once the record has been added to the table and I call `Me.MyList.Requery`, `MyList` pulls the data from `tblMyData`, which is already sorted, including the **newly** added record.

It would be difficult to know where that added record is if there are 1000s of records to scroll through in the list.

Therefore, is there way to go about highlighting the row in the `List Box` containing that **recently** added record to ensure it has been added correctly?

I would like to call it after `Me.MyList.Requery`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't.

But why not set the *value* of the ListBox to that of the newly entered value?

That would display that entry right away. Something like:

```
Dim Criteria As String

Criteria = _
    "FirstName = '" & Me.textBox_FirstName & "' And " & _
    "MiddleName = '" & Me.textBox_MiddleName & "' And " & _
    "LastName = '" & Me.textBox_LastName & "' And " & _
    "YesNoField = " & Me.checkbox_Something & ""

Me!MyList.Value = DLookup("ID", "tblMyData", Criteria)
```

Comment: not sure what you mean (still learning), can you provide code sample based on my example?

Comment: tried your suggestion but I'm getting an error: `Data type mismatch in criteria expression`. I do see that when I do a `Debug.Print Criteria`, the following shows: `FirstName = 'John' And MiddleName = 'David' And LastName = 'Doe'` which is the data that I input....however, I'm not exactly sure what the issue is

Comment: It may be that the _bound column_ of the listbox is not ID. It should be so, however, with an assigned columnwidth of zero, as you probably don't want to display the ID.

Comment: I actually resolved it, in my real code, I have some `Text Box` and `Check Box`...i.e. `Me.checkBox_Something`, and when I removed the `Check Box` from the criteria....i.e. `"MyCheckBox = '" & Me.checkBox_Something & "'` it worked fine, but is there a way to include the `Check Box` in the criteria?....The `True` or `False` values of the `Check Box` are just strings also, so I'm not sure why it is complaining?

Comment: That's because `True/False` _not_ are text. See extended answer, please.

Comment: great!....one last question...is there a reason why you used the bang notation vs dot notation? I used the dot notation, i.e. `Me.MyList.Value` and the result was the same

Comment: In some rare cases dots only can cause misbehaviour. So, it's mostly a matter of preference. The Bang clearly indicates, that `MyList` is a _control_, not a method or property.